# Проблема с входом в убунту

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

Оставил ноутбук на пару минут(lenovo yoga 530).Экран заблокировался и я не мог ввести пароль. Перезагрузил и теперь требуют пароль и логин. Но язык на английский сменить не могу. Можно ли что сделать? Или надо будет переустанавливать убунту?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/USB_flash_installation_medium

Comment: попробуй win+space (супер+пробел)